# Group and Summarize Time Series Transactions with Start and Stop Times

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, window-functions, analytic-functions

I have a series of transactions. I need to summarize the total time spent working on these transactions and a count of transactions within groups that break when you move from one group to another. This means that the group can repeat if there is a set of transactions for that group for multiple time slots. I am using an oracle database and SQL to do this summarization. I'm looking for some help writing the SQL to summarize this data. I've tried many different queries using various analytical and grouping functions.

Source Data:

```
User ID | Area | Start Time | End Time | Transaction ID
jsmith  24  07-JUL-14 09.06.21.000000000 AM 07-JUL-14 09.14.51.000000000 AM 63665020
jsmith  24  07-JUL-14 11.06.01.000000000 AM 07-JUL-14 11.07.10.000000000 AM 63679145
jsmith  24  07-JUL-14 11.16.36.000000000 AM 07-JUL-14 11.16.51.000000000 AM 63680441
jsmith  21  07-JUL-14 11.33.05.000000000 AM 07-JUL-14 11.33.18.000000000 AM 63683133
jsmith  21  07-JUL-14 11.48.55.000000000 AM 07-JUL-14 11.51.03.000000000 AM 63685906
jsmith  21  07-JUL-14 11.55.48.000000000 AM 07-JUL-14 11.56.01.000000000 AM 63686651
jsmith  24  07-JUL-14 12.32.51.000000000 PM 07-JUL-14 12.32.55.000000000 PM 63690943
jsmith  24  07-JUL-14 12.32.55.000000000 PM 07-JUL-14 12.33.02.000000000 PM 63690956
jsmith  21  07-JUL-14 12.42.05.000000000 PM 07-JUL-14 12.42.11.000000000 PM 63692212
jsmith  21  07-JUL-14 12.44.38.000000000 PM 07-JUL-14 12.44.43.000000000 PM 63692600
jsmith  25  07-JUL-14 01.01.18.000000000 PM 07-JUL-14 01.01.52.000000000 PM 63694808
jsmith  25  07-JUL-14 01.03.43.000000000 PM 07-JUL-14 01.04.44.000000000 PM 63695353
jsmith  25  07-JUL-14 01.12.30.000000000 PM 07-JUL-14 01.14.06.000000000 PM 63697002
jsmith  24  07-JUL-14 01.14.11.000000000 PM 07-JUL-14 01.14.23.000000000 PM 63697045
jsmith  24  07-JUL-14 01.21.41.000000000 PM 07-JUL-14 01.23.46.000000000 PM 63699080
```

Summary Data Desired: (mock up)

```
User ID | Area | Start Time | End Time | Total Minutes | Total Transactions
jsmith    24          9:06am   11:16am     110              3 
jsmith    21         11:33am   11:56am      23              3 
jsmith    24    .....
jsmith    21    .....
jsmith    25    .....
jsmith    24    .....
```

Comment: don't think an analytic is needed here just aggregates.

Comment: I don't understand how/why you have several rows  with Area=24 in the desired output. How exactly are grouped your "transactions" ?

Comment: When a different area is encountered it denotes a new grouping set so the first 3 24's together the next 3 21's, the next 2 24's, the next 2 21's, the next 3 25s... etc.  Now I think the analytic LEAD and lag may be useful and wrapping it in a CTE that then is grouped...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve such issues, you need to generate some *group number* for each consecutive rows. Here I first use `LAG` to generate a tick mark each time we start a new group. An outer query using `SUM` will count the number of tick marks from the first from to the current one to generate a group number:

```
SELECT "Area", 
       MIN("Start Time") as "Start Time", 
       MAX("End Time") as "End Time",  
       SUM("End Time" - "Start Time")*24*60 as "Total Minutes", 
       COUNT("Transaction ID") as "#Transaction ID"
FROM (
  SELECT SUM(clk)
         OVER (ORDER BY "Start Time"
               ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) grp,
--       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
--        Generate a group number by summing the tick marks
         V1.*
  FROM (
    SELECT CASE
             WHEN LAG("Area", 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY "Start Time") = "Area"
             THEN 0
             ELSE 1
           END clk,
--         ^^^^^^^^
--         Set a tick mark ("clock") to 1 each time we change group
         T.*
    FROM T
    ) V1
  ) V2
GROUP BY GRP, "Area"
ORDER BY "Start Time"
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93f05/2

---

A little bit more difficult to grasp, but this works too:

```
SELECT "Area", 
       MIN("Start Time") as "Start Time", 
       MAX("End Time") as "End Time",  
       SUM("End Time" - "Start Time")*60 as "Total Minutes", 
       COUNT("Transaction ID") as "#Transaction ID"
FROM (
  SELECT ROWNUM-ROW_NUMBER() 
                   OVER (PARTITION BY "Area" ORDER BY "Start Time") grp,
       T.*
  FROM T
  ORDER BY "Start Time"
) V
GROUP BY GRP, "Area"
ORDER BY "Start Time"
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/07d43/6

In that case, beware that you can have duplicate `grp` -- but only for different group. Unless the rows are contiguous. Please refer to the comments bellow for a discussion about that.

Comment: I'm in awe of how you came up with the concept; but I'm struggling with if this would ever encounter duplicate grp numbers.

Comment: Thank you! This concept really helped, and it looks like I am able to get what I need. We want duplicate group numbers to track the metrics throughout the day as the user is working in different groups. Example: group A in the morning then to group B then back to A and then on to C.

Comment: @xQbert Perfectly right! I don't know how I couldn't think about that. Of course, you can craft data for having duplicate grp numbers. I switched my answer for a more simple solution -- *that* time, it is certain that you don't have duplicates...

Comment: @xQbert As a matter of fact, [my original answer](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/07d43/6) worked well as you can have duplicates grp -- but not for the same `"Area"` unless the rows are contiguous. This was taken into account by the `GROUP BY GRP, "Area"`.